# Get array of objects based on specific object Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my Mongodb structure

```
    id:111
    article:Array
    0:Object
    articleid:"123"
    1:Object
    articleid:"456"

    id:222
    article:Array
    0:Object
    articleid:"789"
```

I want to get users based on articleid. If one user based on articleid is getting fine. But i have few articleid's, based on this articleid's i want to get users.

I tried like this

```
Collections.user.find({},{article:{$elemMatch:{articleid:req.body.Articleid}}})
```

but not working, when i check 
console.log(req.body.Articleid)

```
["456", "789"]
```

I need to get users based on this articleid's.

Comment: Try this `Collections.user.find({ articleid: { $in: req.body.Articleid }})`

Answer (score 0):

Correct your query to:

```
Collections.user.find({'article.articleid':req.body.Articleid}}})
```

**Explanation:** The first argument is the query, second one is just for projection.

Comment: Not working. It gives article array of all users. but what i need is which user match with articleid, i need to get that specific user.